# f analytic in a domain contains unit disk, prove the equation of the sum of the square of coefficient modulus

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=a_{n}z^{n}$ analytic in a domain containg unit disk,prove that
$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}|f(e^{i \theta})|^{2} d \theta= \Sigma |a_{n}|^{2} $

Thanks for the hint $|f(z)|^{2}=f \bar{f} = \Sigma a_{n}\bar{a_{m}}z^{n}\bar{z}^{m}$, but I'm still a little confused about the next steps.... I'm not sure how to get the right hand side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hint:
$$
\int_\gamma z^n \overline{z}^m\,dz=0,\quad n\neq m
$$
where $\gamma$ is the unit circle. This can be shown easily if you use a parameterization of the circle and directly do the calculation.

Now try integration term by term.

Comment: Thank you for your hint it really helps a lot!